# In Python, how do I remove the last tuple (None,) in a list? The list mixes with string and floats

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list (mixed with string and values) like below:

```
mylist = [('Needie', 83, 55, 78, None), ('Blue', 80, 60, None, 66), ('Bloodnok', None, 54, 57, 59), (None,)]
```

The desired output should be:

```
newlist = [('Needie', 83, 55, 78, None), ('Blue', 80, 60, None, 66), ('Bloodnok', None, 54, 57, 59)]
```

What should I do to remove the last tuple (None,) in the list? Keep other tuples as before, includes names (string), None value and floats

```
del list[:-1]
```

**Output:**

```
[(None,)]
```

Comment: `del list[-1]` should do it (changes the existing list), as would `newlist = list[:-1]` (assigns a changed copy to `newlist` and leaves `list` intact).

Comment: ahhhh, that's why. Thanks Zinki.